# background and textcolor navbar Blazor

Tags: bootstrap-4, navbar, background-color, blazor

I would like to change the background color of a navbar in Blazor, but I cannot find the way to do it. It cannot be that difficult, I guess. Can anybody tell me?

```
<div class="top-row pl-4 navbar navbar-dark bg-primary ">
    <a class="navbar-brand bg-primary" href="">Test</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler bg-primary" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon bg-primary"></span>
    </button>
</div>

<div class="@NavMenuCssClass" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
    <ul class="nav flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item px-3 bg-primary">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
            </NavLink>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item px-3 bg-primary oi-resize-height">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="hd">
                <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> hd
            </NavLink>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The answer is probably in the bootstrap 4 doc : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/navbar/#color-schemes

Answer (score 10):

In "MainLayout.razor"

```html
<div style="background-image:none;background-color:cadetblue;" class="sidebar">
    <NavMenu />
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Late answer I was reviewing first posts.
In app.css in the client change the sidebar class :

```
.sidebar {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

Comment: When using Blazor Server, you can find the sidebar class in the MainLayout.razor.css file.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is due to `blazor` having its own `css` file we need to change the `css` there.

To change the `background-color` of the sidebar and navbar, in `MainLayout.razor.css` thats where the `css` is located e.g.`.sidbar` `.top-row`

and finally to change the background of the area where the "Company/project logo" is going to be, for the the css is under `NavMenu.razor.css --> .top-row`

Answer (score 0):

This answer navbar blazer button, remove bg-primary and add **bg-secondary** bootstrap class is using change the button color.

```
<button class="navbar-toggler bg-secondary" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon "></span>
</button>

// or try this css

.navbar-toggler{
   background:coral !important;
 }
```